# C# Entity Framework Custom Constraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am currently trying to make a custom constraint with the C# Entity Framework. In more detail:

I have a number field which only can have certain values (for example 1, 2 and 3). How do I achieve this constraint in a code first environment?

Comment: What's with all the Entity Framework tags?

Comment: Sorry, removed the duplicate ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework automatically validates any validations you add to your model by [`ValidationAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)s. `RequiredAttribute` or `RangeAttribute` are two examples of built-in subclasses of this attribute.

If you want some custom validation, the most convenient way is to piggyback on this mechanism and create you own `ValidationAttribute` subclass.

If you want to validate a non-contiguous range of values you can't use `RangeAttribute` but you could make an own attribute, for instance like this:

```
public class AllowedValuesAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly ICollection<object> _validValues;
    private readonly Type _type;

    public AllowedValuesAttribute(Type type, object[] validValues)
    {
        _type = type;
        _validValues = validValues.Where(v => v != null && v.GetType() == type).ToList();
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return value.GetType() == _type && _validValues.Contains(value);
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format("Value for '{0}' is not an allowed value", name);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[AllowedValues(typeof(int), new object[] { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 })]
public int Base { get; set; }
```

Note that we have to use fixed values here, because the content of the attribute must be known at compile time. Also, we have to use `object` because (currently) C# doesn't support generic attributes. Apart from that, there are numerous options. For example, the attribute could also have a method that finds allowed values at runtime, maybe from a named source, so you can supply this name in its constructor.

I don't see any problem in adorning entity classes with validation attributes. The entity model is *not* a domain model, it's part of a data access layer. It's primary purpose is (and should be) to facilitate an application's data access. If an entity model also happens to support business logic that's a mere bonus.

Comment: after thinking about it, I still have no idea why s.o. would use this. An attribute for this is simple the wrong way. Your example shows it: here, it'd be a `Flag`-`Enum` or a simple `Enum`, if the values were e.g. `1,3,7,20,...`. If the data has a specific meaning you would create a table and use the PK as FK. If you really have to use int (because, don't know why), you would handle it in the controller or use the annotation on viewmodel, since other controller maybe could enter other int - (if not, enum or FK it).. Sorry, but I still don't see any reason for using it on an entity-class.

Comment: @MatthiasBurger In an application you want to have a *single point of validation*. I would never use a property setter that throws an exception. That introduces many potential code locations where exceptions must be handled. And when EF's validation kicks in, the property doesn't validate. The advantage of an attribute is that it validates at the right time and in the right way, i.e. just as other EF validations. Any violations are listed nicely among other validation errors. You get a lot for free.

Comment: @MatthiasBurger Of course I wouldn't use it for FK checking and yes, I'd recommend enums. An attribute could suffice in relatively simple cases.

Comment: the validation-issue is correct and I agree in this point. But imo the entity-class is too late for this kind of validation. Since it's a view validation, I think, it should already gets validated in a viewmodel (unless you don't use viewmodels and take the entity-classes into your views). The viewmodel could also be a base-class for viewmodels, so you **have** that single point of validation. E.g. an `AccountViewModel` is base for `LoginViewModel` and `RegisterViewModel`. I'd validate the mail-address in `AccountViewModel` and send valid data to entity-class `Applicationuser`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @MatthiasBurger *That* I fully agree with :) I don't like to throw full entity objects over the wire. But view models could also have attributes. It all depends on preferences. For example, with ASP.Net MVC, working with validation attributes (on whatever model class) is very convenient. Still, validation attributes (or implementing `IValidatableObject` --my preference) in entity classes offer a nice final guard against junk entering the database.

Comment: long discussion and too less characters to enter :D - finally, I agree with you, but think this is a lot about preferences and coding style :) - but it's always good to hear/read what other programmers think. It just makes my code better :)

Answer (score 0):

It's very bad practice to add dataannotations in domain-model, like D.Mac wrote.
So what about doing it the nicer way?

```
public MyClass
{    
    private int myNumberField;
    public int MyNumberField 
    { 
        get { return myNumberField; } 
        set
        { 
            if (value >= 1 && value <=3)
                myNumberField = value;
            else
                // throw exception?
                // set default-value (maybe 1)?
                // do nothing?
        }
    }

}
```

you could do whatever you want in the setter of your property

and only restricting it in the front-end is not the best solution, since you always can modify javascript/html - but you should show the user, that he only can insert values 1, 2 or 3. 
Also restrict it in the viewmodel with data annotations.

OR:

you could also override EntityFrameworks `SaveChanges` and add your businesslogic:

```
public override int SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
{

    foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in
        ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
        EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified))
    {
        // Validate the objects in the Added and Modified state
        // if the validation fails, e.g. throw an exeption.
    }
    return base.SaveChanges(options);
}
```